# Mask Won't Stay After Converting Image

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, mask

I'm having trouble with masking a .png image and then converting that image to RGB. I'm doing this to make the mask effect more visible on a white background.

I've done the `.convert('RGB')` method before saving, and pasting the masked image onto a newly created white image. Both have no effect on the starting image:

```py
from PIL import Image
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/'

mask = Image.open(path + "snap_mask.png")
mask = mask.convert("L")
im = Image.open(path + "snap.png")
im.putalpha(mask)

im.convert('RGB').save(path + "snap_output.png")
```

The starting image and the final result end up being the same. Here are the links to the images I'm using (it's for a discord bot):

[snap.png](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg)
(right side of image is grey so particle effect can be seen)

[snap_mask.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H9s8.png)

[snap_output.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NNXp.png)

[desired_output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPLmG.png)
(the output I want)

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: By converting the image to RGB, you throw away the alpha channel you just added to it.

Comment: Ah okay. That helps, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after taking a short break, I realized what I was doing wrong. Instead of converting the image to RGB, I resorted to adding a white image behind the mask. I was doing the `.paste()` method improperly before, and was able to get the desired final output:

```py
from PIL import Image
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + '/'

mask = Image.open(path + "snap_mask.png")
mask = mask.convert("L")
dst_im = Image.open(path + "snap.png")
dst_im.putalpha(mask)

white = Image.new('RGB', dst_im.size, (255, 255, 255))
white.paste(dst_im, dst_im)

white.save(path + "snap_output.png")
```